# 2 NSDateComponents - is it same week?

Tags: objective-c, nsdatecomponents

i have got a function with BOOL return value and 2 input (NSDateComponents *) parameters.
My trouble is I have two NSDateComponents values and I want to know if the two date fall within the same calendar week. i tried the simplest solutions to solve problem, my idea was the following:

`- (BOOL)isFunctionName:(NSDateComponents *)comp1 andParam:(NSDateComponents *)comp2 {
    return (([comp1 week] == [comp2 week]) && ([comp1 year] == [comp2 year]));
}`

but it's not correct. 
what way i can solve it ?

---

edited

so i have a function which makes datecomponents from dates.

`-(NSDateComponents *)dateToDateComponents:(NSDate *)date {
    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
    [gregorian release];
    return dateComponents;
}`

and i call it this way:

`if ([self isFunctionName: [self dateToDateComponents:startDate]  and Param:[self dateToDateComponents:currentTripDate]]){
}`

and during my test it returns YES  all of my dates (for example 2010.07.21 - 2010.08.18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSDateComponent class reference states:

> **Important:**  An `NSDateComponents` object is meaningless in itself; you
>   need to know what calendar it is
>   interpreted against, and you need to
>   know whether the values are absolute
>   values of the units, or quantities of
>   the units.

What about comparing `NSDate`s instead?

```
- (BOOL) weekIsEqual:(NSDate *)date and:(NSDate *)otherDate {
  NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

  NSDateComponents *dateComponents      = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
  NSDateComponents *otherDateComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:otherDate];

  return [dateComponents week] == [otherDateComponents week] && [dateComponents year] == [otherDateComponents year];
}
```

---

**edit**:
In this line:

```
 unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

You don't pass `NSWeekCalendarUnit`, therefore `[dateComponent week]` returns `NSUndefinedDateComponent`

**edit**

Of course, it has to be `NSWeekCalendarUnit`…

Comment: i call my functions as following: 
if ([self isFunctionName: [self dateToDateComponents:startDate]  and Param:[self dateToDateComponents:currentTripDate]]){
}

Comment: there is dateToDateComponents function, which is makes DateComponents from dates

unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
[gregorian release];
return dateComponents;

Comment: so it was two dates, and i want to handle them.

Comment: ok i see, added NSWeekdayCalendarUnit, and afterward i got EXC_BAD_ACCES after NSLog(@"comp1 week: %@" [comp1 week]) :S

Comment: [comp1 week] returns an NSInteger, if you use e.g. NSLog(@"%@", 34), the 34 will be dereferenced as if it was a pointer which will cause the bad access signal.

Try
NSLog(@"comp1 week: %i", [comp1 week]);
instead

Comment: in the meantime I've tried many solutions, %i was good idea, but comp week value is 2147483647 (upper limit of NSInteger) still don't have result :/

Comment: You have to pass `NSWeekCalendarUnit` to get the date component that corresponds to the week.

Comment: This doesn't work when the week crosses between two years. For example, 12/31/2012 and 1/1/2013. Robert's method will return NO, while in applications YES is the expected answer. – Joseph Lin 1 min ago edit

Comment: Many things are deprecated now, for example NSGregorianCalendar

Answer (score 2):

This is inspired by Robert's answer. I tweaked it a bit to address the issue when a week crosses two years, e.g. 12/31/2012 & 1/1/2013.

```
- (BOOL)isOnSameWeekAsDate:(NSDate*)otherDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:self];
    NSDateComponents *otherComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:otherDate];

    return ( [components yearForWeekOfYear] == [otherComponents yearForWeekOfYear] && [components weekOfYear] == [otherComponents weekOfYear] );
}
```

Comment: I think this is THE answer. I have not found it elsewhere on the web. The constants you are using are deprecated, though.

Comment: Your answer is not useful any more in iOS8... see http://nshipster.com/nscalendar-additions/

Comment: Keep it for iOS7 et before... I tried to find a solution for `isOnPreviousWeek`... Can you do it easily?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS8, this became much easier:

```
-(BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date1 onSameWeekAs:(NSDate *)date2
{
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDate:date1
                                    equalToDate:date2
                              toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear];
}
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/isDate:equalToDate:toUnitGranularity:):

> returns YES if both dates have equal date component for all units
>   greater than or equal to the given unit, otherwise NO.